# Best way to stream audio from Firebase without using a ton of gigabytes?React native Expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

Ive been using firebase storage to store my music and directly been streaming them from their audio address to my app but when I stream like around 5 songs it tells me a whole gigabyte has been used.This is my code

```
const Tracks = [
  {
    id: 0,
    
    track: {uri:'https://firebasestorage.googleapis._wind_trees_leaves_falling_qld_australia_56740.mp3?alt=media&token=5-436c-ad4b-1497110c3c2f'},
    
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    track: {uri:'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.cot.com/o/song%20files%2FChocolate%20Cookie%20Jam%20-%20An%20Jone.mp3?alt=media&token=5-89ef-ec154734c584' },
   
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    track: {uri:'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b.com/o/song%20files%2Fmelatonin%2FAtch%20-%20All%20The%20Same.wav?alt=media&token=b4-403b-b455-cc1c115d463c' },
   
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    track: {uri:'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.co0files%2F(Sax%2C%20Dance)%20Luke%20Bergs%20-%20Dance%20%5BFTUM%20Release%5D.wav?alt=media&token=613d4b05-4ec7bff3b453' },
  ] ...


export default function VibeScreen ({navigation, props})  {
    
  
  const [Loaded, SetLoaded] = React.useState(false);
  const [Loading, SetLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [CurrentSong, SetCurrentSong] = React.useState(Tracks[0]);
  const sound = React.useRef(new Audio.Sound());

  React.useEffect(() => {
    LoadAudio();

    return () => Unload();
  }, [CurrentSong]);

  const Unload = async () => {
    await sound.current.unloadAsync();
  };

  const PlayAudio = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await sound.current.getStatusAsync();
      if (result.isLoaded) {
        if (result.isPlaying === false) {
          sound.current.playAsync();
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }; ...<TouchableOpacity onPress={PlayAudio}>
```

Is there a more efficient way to stream audio from firebase without using so much storage download ? Sorry Im still alittle new to firebase and servers.

Comment: The question is a little vague and without knowing the specific size of each of the 5 songs, we would just be guessing. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Sorry about that, each song is about 2-3 mins long and i was a bit exaggerating with 1GB. But i just tested it and after playing 7 songs, firebase says i used 315mb of storage data already. Is that normal for streaming audio and do you think I should keep my audio stored in my apps local storage? Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for your help but i just converted them from Wav to Mp3 and compressed them down a bit and now it only takes 20mb to play 9 songs! Quality is honestly barely noticeably different too.